# Bind to bound item?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, windows-8.1

I have `Comments` class, to which I am binding:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CommentFiles}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserId}"/> <!-- Here should be username -->
                    <TextBlock Text=","/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedAt}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

As you can see `Comments` class have `UserId` property, which is just some char combination. I can get `User` class object with asynchronous `getUser(userID)` method.
I want to see user's username(which is in `User` class) instead of UserId, when I bind to comments.
And I cannot edit classes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just bind to UserName instead of UserId?

Comment: @Breeze Because `Comments` class doesn't have UserName property, and I cannot change classes.

Comment: Does the comments class have any reference to the user? How do you link the comment to the user?

Comment: how about use a converter and return UserName via reflection?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see that there are different classes. But what about creating a Property inside Comments that returns the value of the User's UserName?

Comment: @Aetherix Comments class has UserId property, by which I can get User class object.

Comment: @Helic could you please explain that in more details?

Comment: Look up converter on msdn

Comment: Create a custom extended 'Comments' class, and load the existing comments object into the new extended class and expose the properties. There you can add properties as much as you like, e.g. User. And then load the user by the UserId.

Comment: @dace please see unkreativ's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could Bind the userId in combination with a value converter that takes the userId, calls getUser(value) and returns the user name.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding UserId, Converter={StaticResource MyUserIdConverter}" />
```

And the value converter would look like:

```
public class MyUserIdConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Add some checks here ;-)
        return GetUser((string) value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that work with asynchronous method? Because I prevoiusly forgot to mention that getUser method is asynchronous method.

Comment: @dace return GetUser((string)name).Result; the async method will be called each time the converter is invoked, the async method may be slow to return the result and cause display issue on GUI.

Comment: you can use prioritybinding to show the "Loading state" till the async method is ready

Answer (score 0):

A little example based on my comment. You can either load the complete user, or only the username.

```
public class ExtendedCommentFile
{
    private readonly CommentFile _comment;

    public ExtendedComment(CommentFile comment)
    {
        _comment = comment;
    }

    public int UserId
    {
        get { return _comment.UserId; }
        set { _comment.UserId = value; }
    }

    public User User
    {
        get { return LoadTheUserHereOrInVM(); }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return LoadTheUserNameHereOrInVM(); }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the unchangeable commentfile class
/// </summary>
public class CommentFile
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is unchangeable user class
/// </summary>
public class User
{
}
```